# Why is MATLAB displaying 1.0000 when I do 1+eps?

Tags: matlab, floating-point

If I do the following in MATLAB:

```
y = 1+eps
```

I get the following output:

```
1.000000000000000
```

Why is it not displaying the 'eps' portion that I added to '1' and stored in y? Is this a limitation of matlab, where although it can store 1+eps, it cannot display it or am I totally misunderstanding 'eps'?

Comment: What do you get if you now evaluate `y - 1`?

Comment: Try `fprintf("%.20f\n", y)`. When outputting it probably only outputs a certain number of digits so this tells it to output $20$ digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eps = 2.220446049250313E-16, or Eps = .0000000000000002220....

Notice how Eps has 15 zeros and then its significant digits. Well what Matlab is displaying is up to 15 decimal places. When adding 1 and Eps only the 15 0's that were added are displayed.

Comment: I see, but "inside" it is actually storing 1+eps then because there are enough bits to store it?

Comment: Correct. If you want Matlab to display the Epsilon part, you must have it display more digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format long` to get 15 digits, although I'm not sure if that is enough the number in question is very small.

also see the documentation:

http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-format-for-numeric-values.html

http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html